# How to redirect old url to new url in rails using just routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The old sitemap of my application has already been indexed to Google now. For some one visiting my rails app with old url shouldn't go to 404. 
The old url looked like this

`/search?sub_category=210`

Now after making them friendly, it looks like this:

`/search?sub_category=milling-and-drilling`.

I tried redirecting it from controller but it causes too much issues on other things. Such as filters which are using the same `params`. Is there a way I can do it from routes file?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `redirect_to route_path(id)` you would do `redirect_to route_path(object.find_by_id(id).name)`

Comment: where should I add this ?

Comment: You mean something like this `redirect_to search_equipments_path(sub_category: sub_cat.name.parameterize)` in controller

Comment: So in your controller where you would normally do `redirect_to search_equipments_path(params[:id)` you would do `redirect_to search_equipments_path(Category.find_by_id(params[:id]).name)`. This is assuming the new search is for a Categories name instead of the standard id.

Answer (score 0):

> How to redirect old url to new url in rails using just routes?

AFAIK (As far as I know), **no. (if through params)**

The main job of routes.rb is to determine what "code" will handle the request, particularly that which matches `request.url` and the `request.method`. It does not concern yet of the request parameters nor its values: these would be handled in the controllers itself. Although, you can route based on parameters (or any information about the "request") through a [routes constraint](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints)

### Alternative Solution:

Instead of finding by ID, now find by "Slug name or ID".
In your models, particularly in this specific example of yours, add something like:

```
class SubCategory < ApplicationRecord

  # if you're using a gem for the "friendly" urls, you don't need this method, and just use theirs.
  def self.friendly_find!(friendly_id)
    # this may not necessarily be `name`, maybe `slug`? or depending on your case
    find_by(name: friendly_id) || find(friendly_id)
  end
end
```

And in your controllers, just replace wherever you're finding a record (maybe also to other models not just `SubCategory` as needed be),  particularly in your `search` action:

```
def search
  sub_category = SubCategory.friendly_find!(params[:sub_category])
end
```

NOTE: `friendly_find!` will raise an Error if no record is found.